# Pipeline forking in shell

Tags: bash, shell, pipe, pipeline

First of all, I tried to search similar topics in Google and Stackoverflow but I didn't find anything similar.

**QUESTION:**

Is there any way to handle pipeling forking in shell?

**EXAMPLE:**

I've the following directory tree:

```
> 1
>> 1.a
>> 2.a
>> 3.a
> 2
>> 1.b
>> 2.b
>> 3.b
```

When I execute the command:

```
ls -1 */* | nl
```

I get the following output:

```
1  1/1.a
2  1/2.a
3  1/3.a
4  2/1.b
5  2/2.b
6  2/3.b
```

If I'd like to refer to the first column, I'd use cut with -f1 parameter. In the same way, if I'd like to refer to the second column, I'd user the -f2 parameter. Could I use the below command in some manner?

```
ls -1 */* | nl | mv `cut -d'   ' -f1` `cut -d'    ' -f2`
```

I don't mind the way of renaming the files. I actually want to know if parallel pipelining exists in shell.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? If I interpret the `mv` it looks like you're trying to do something like `mv 1 1.a`. Did you mean something like `mv 1.a 1`?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the directory prefix, so it'd be: `mv 1/1.a 1`

Answer (score 2):

Parsing the output of `ls` is [strongly discouraged](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs); I would use the following instead.

```sh
count=1
for f in */*; do
    echo mv "$f" $((count++))
done
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this for loop:

```
while read -r f1 f2; do
   [[ -n "$f1" && -n "$f2" ]] && mv "$f1/$f2" "$f2"
done < <(ls -1 */* | nl)
```

Here is a **non-BASH script**:

```
ls -1 */* | nl | while read -r f1 f2; do
   [ -n "$f1" ] && [ -n "$f2" ] && mv "$f1/$f2" "$f2"
done
```

Comment: Since OP has used `BASH` tag it is better to use `[[ ... ]]` rather than old `[ ... ]`

Comment: @GoodPerson: with `[[`, the `&&` is an option that is not available with `[` (which is presumably what you're advocating).  Since the question is tagged, a Bash-only solution is OK, though since it is also tagged Shell, a more nearly neutral solution would be good, too.

Comment: Even if portability were a concern, the POSIX spec itself recommends `[ -n "$f1" ] && [ -n "$f2" ]` over `[ -n "$f1" -a -n "$f2" ]`.

Comment: Without BASH even process substitution `< <(...)` won't work.

Comment: @anubhava many OPs tag things as bash when they don't realize that 'shell' != 'bash'

Comment: @GoodPerson Then the tag should be corrected; there's no need to read the user's mind.

Comment: Both are ways of getting the job done. But they don't use what I'm looking for (forking pipes).

Comment: @chepner and we should be explaining to the user the most portable solution possible and encouraging them to retag their question.

Comment: @displayer: Can you clarify what exactly you want by **forking pipes**

Comment: @displayer What you are looking for doesn't exist; *this* is the solution to your problem, whether or not it looks like what you thought you wanted.